# Deriving the Wilmore equations

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to derive the Euler-Lagrange equation from the Wilmore functional $\displaystyle W(\Sigma) = \int_{\Sigma} H^2\cdot dA$, where $\Sigma$ is some surface. The resulting equation should be

$$\Delta H + 2H(H^2-K) = 0,$$

here $H$ denotes the mean curvature, $K$ is the Gaussian curvature and $\Delta$ denotes the Laplace–Beltrami operator. I'm really clueless on how one would obtain a derivation of this in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with some equipped metric. There's a proof on [page 2 here](https://pcmi.ias.edu/files/Willmore_Euler-Lagrange_Equations.pdf) but it uses a lot of heavy machinery which is difficult for me to follow. Is it possible to derive the said expression using the basic principles from calculus of variations? I've only taken an introductory course on differential geometry and self studied basic calculus of variations.

Comment: I would say that your linked proof is very standard and probably the easiest one. Which parts do you not understand?

Comment: @JohnMa Can you explain what the $(I_t)_{ij}$ means in the sentence below (6.3)

Comment: $I_t$ is the second fundamental form.

Comment: You may take a look at Joel Persson's [Master's Thesis](http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/students/Joel-Persson-MSc.pdf) that seems to be more accessible and self contained that those lecture notes that you've mentioned (pretty wonderful, by the way).